# list index out of range (but i just need to check if the index exists)

Tags: python, list

Is there some way to check if a list index exists? I'm currently working on a maze, and I need to display the available directions, and I used a list to navigate my way through the maze, although I keep getting errors

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code goes like this:

```
    if x+grid <= len(maze) and temp == 0 and maze[x+grid][1] == " ":
        avdir.append("South")
# avdir stands for available directions
```

The index is up to 8 only.

basically i want the output to be like:

if index exists and passes certain conditions, add this direction to the list

Comment: The indices go from 0 to ```len(maze)```, EXCLUDING ```len(maze)```. So the comparison should be ```if x + grid < len(maze)```

Comment: replace `x+grid <= len(maze)` with `x+grid < len(maze)`